# How to determine if 5 digit number is a palindrome using an array?

Tags: java

I'm in a beginning java class and having a tough time with this one. My professor gave us this pseudocode - 
create string sInput

```
//
//    prompt for input
//
//    create char array (cArray) and assign sInput.toCharArray()
//
//    loop to check for palindrome (set i = 0, j = sInput.length()-1, check to see if i != j; increment i, decrement j)
//        check to see if current array values are !=
//            print not a palindrome
//            return
//        end of loop
```

I am at wit's end. Thanks for any suggestions!

I have

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
while (true) {
display(check(retrieveInput()));
}
}

public static String retrieveInput() {
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
return scan.next();
}

public static boolean check(String input) {
boolean check = false;
try {
Integer.parseInt(input);
if (input.charAt(0)==input.charAt(4) && input.charAt(1)==input.charAt(3))
check = true;

} catch(Exception e) {
check = false;
}

return check;
}

public static void display(boolean check) {
if(check) System.out.println("Is a five-digit palindrome.");
else System.out.println("Is not a five-digit palindrome.");
```

Comment: even we would have given you the algorithm only. Try something, and if you're stuck up, come back here.

Comment: Sorry, do your own homework. If/when you have some ACTUAL code that's not working, we'll maybe help fix it. but some comments don't really indicate you've actually done ANYTHING on this yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps:

public static void main(String[] args) {

```
    boolean notPalindrome = false;
    String number = "25852";
    char[] array = number.toCharArray();
    for(int i=0, j=array.length-1; i<j; i++, j--) {
        if(array[i] != array[j]) {
            notPalindrome = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(number + " is palindrome? " + !notPalindrome);
}
```

Comment: It helps tremendously! Thanks for contributing.

Comment: +1, I didn't know this was possible, `for(int i=0, j=array.length-1; i<j; i++, j--)`